# Kentico CMS: Add a class attribute to the html tag in a Kentico Masterpage

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

How do you edit the HTML tag in a Kentico CMS Masterpage, i.e. to add a class attribute?

Currently I have this:

[image: Kentico masterpage html tag]

But I want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="myClass">
  <head>
    <title>
```

From the screenshot you can see that the HTML tag is not editable.

Is there a way to edit the html tag or tell Kentico to write a class attribute to the html tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one solution:

I manually added a class attribute to the HTML tag in this file:-

`<solution>/CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx`

Comment: this is the only solution I have found so far.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is a horrible one.  Modifying base code isn't a preferred method at all.  Try adding some custom code in to an output filter or even in a template where you can modify the body tag like in this post: http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/use-page-template-name-as-a-class-in-the-ascx-master-template

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "Head HTML" web part on your page template(s).

Comment: I can edit the html tag in the HEAD HTML web part? can you provide a little more detail of how I do this please.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite disappointing that Kentico still does not support this out of the box. A request to be able to modify the `<html>` tag directly from code has been filed: http://ideas.kentico.com/forums/239189-kentico-product-ideas/suggestions/5947264-ability-to-modify-page-head-section-and-html-tag
In the meantime use the following solutions:

### Portal Engine

I solved this the following way, based on [Dave Haigh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10798442/548020) suggestion.  In the file `/CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx` change the following line:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <%=XmlNamespace%>
    lang="<%=CMSContext.PreferredCultureCode%>">
```

### ASPX Engine

In your master page, add the following snippet to your code behind file:

```html
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CurrentDocument != null)
    {          
        CMS.UIControls.ContentPage page= this.Page as CMS.UIControls.ContentPage;
        if (page != null)
        {
            string lang= CMS.Localization.LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture.CultureCode;
            page.XmlNamespace += " lang=\"" + lang + "\"";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

*Source: http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/kentico-9-how-to-define-language-in-html*

Comment: Is there a solution for sites that store all of their code in the database?  I don't have access to the code for the custom Master page we're using.

Comment: @Janet Unfortunately I cannot help you on this as I stop working with Kentico.